# How to get only 1 column data in JsonResult response in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

This is my code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("CourseWeeks/{id}")]
public JsonResult GetCourseWeeks(int id)
{
    // return new JsonResult(db.CourseWeeks.ToList());
    var courseWeek = db.CourseWeeks
        .Where(c => c.CourseId == id);
        return new JsonResult(courseWeek);
}
```

Currently it's returning all the columns in `db.CourseWeeks` which match the id, but I only want it to return a single column's data only.

Comment: you can use linque to select a single column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can linque to select single column as below I need to check the syntax.

```
var courseWeek = db.CourseWeeks
    .Where(c => c.CourseId == id).select (c=>c.columnname);
```

Comment: @MuhammadHassanNasir Try clicking grey checkmark below arrows instead, thanks